# Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a chain complex. Show that the kernel of the map $A_n/B_n \rightarrow Z_{n-1} $ is isomorphic to $H_{n}(A)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{p_{n+1}} B_n \xrightarrow{r_{n+1}} Z_n \xrightarrow{k_{n+1}} A_n$, where  $k_{n+1} \circ r_{n+1}=i_{n+1}$ is the monomorphism in the image factorization of $d_{n+1}$ the complex map. ($B_n=Im(d_{n+1})$ and $Z_n=Ker(d_n)$)

Let $A_n \xrightarrow{c_{n+1}} Coker(i_{n+1})$ be the cokernel of $i_{n+1}$ and $B_n \rightarrow Z_n \rightarrow H_n(A)$ the cokernel of $r_{n+1}$.

Since $d_n \circ d_{n+1} = i_n \circ p_n \circ i_{n+1} \circ p_{n+1}=0 \implies i_n \circ p_n \circ i_{n+1}=0 \implies p_n \circ i_{n+1}=0$ this implies that we get a map:

$ Coker(i_{n+1}) \xrightarrow{\alpha_n} B_{n-1}$ such that $\alpha_n \circ c_{n+1}= p_n$. Finally we get the map $\xi_n= r_n \circ \alpha_n$.

I want to prove that $Ker(\xi_n)\cong H_n(A)$.

If we compose $ \xi_n \circ c_{n+1} \circ k_{n+1}=r_n \circ \alpha_n \circ c_{n+1} \circ k_{n+1}=r_n \circ p_n \circ k_{n+1}=0$ this yields a map $Z_n \xrightarrow{\beta_n} Ker(\xi_n)$. Such that $\gamma_n \circ \beta_n= c_{n+1} \circ k_{n+1}$ where $\gamma_n$ is the map from the kernel of $\xi_n$ to $Cokernel(i_{n+1})$.

Also $\gamma_n \circ \beta_n \circ r_{n+1}=0 \implies \beta_n \circ r_{n+1}=0$. This also yields a map from $H_n(A)$ to $Ker(\xi_n)$.

And from here I don't know how to continue. I could prove that $Cokernel(\xi_n) \cong H_{n-1}(A)$ but I'm stuck in this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm lost among so many homomorphisms, let's look at the following: $$A_n/B_n\twoheadrightarrow A_n/Z_n\simeq B_{n-1}\hookrightarrow Z_{n-1}.$$ The first map is $a_n\bmod B_n\mapsto a_n\bmod Z_n$, the second is $a_n\bmod Z_n\mapsto d_n(a_n)$, and the second is the inclusion. Then  $a_n\bmod B_n\mapsto 0$ iff $d_n(a_n)=0$ iff $a_n\in Z_n$, that is, the kernel of this map is $Z_n/B_n=H_n(A)$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was thinking that it was very messy while I was writing the question.. Next time I'll add diagrams. 

I came up with this same argument after asking :) . Thanks for your time!